# Stackoverflow Facebook login inside browser in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, authentication, oauth, qr-code, facebook-login

I created a QR code to http://stackoverflow.com here:
http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/801/l1s8dhttp3a2f2fstackove.png

Next, with my iPhone 4 (iOS 6.1.2) I read it with a QR Code Reader (https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/qr-reader-for-iphone/id368494609) with a "inside-browser" and tried to login in stackoverflow with Facebook, but it gave me this error: "An error occurred. Please try again later."

I only have this behavior with iPhone "inside-browsers", there is any explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works on Android with QR Code Reader. I suppose that the app is not exactly the same for iphone and android